# using className and empty string ("").

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with 4 very similar images/icons. When the user clicks on one of the images, it becomes saturated and appears highlighted, until another image is clicked (then that one will be saturated and appear highlighted) it all works, but since i found this little snippet somewhere else, and since i'm using it in my exam project, i need to be able to explain the code. I am having a hard time getting a grasp of the className property, while i also find it a little weird that it is set to an empty string ("") in this example.

The HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul>
        <li><img id="one" onclick="saturate(this); display(this);" src="../images/efficiency.png" alt="efficiency"/></li>
        <li><img id="two" onclick="saturate(this); display(this);" src="../images/educated_team.png"></li>
        <li><img id="three" onclick="saturate(this); display(this);" src="../images/profitable_options.png"></li>
        <li><img id="four" onclick="saturate(this); display(this);" src="../images/strategic_solutions.png"></li>

    </ul>
```

And the JS:

```
 var current = document.getElementById('one');

function saturate(now) {

    if (current != null) {
        current.className = "";
    }

    now.className = "saturate";
    current = now;

}
```

Can anyone, in simple words, explain how this works? How does this make it possible for just a single image to be saturated at a time (much like menu items staying highlighted on click)?
Furthermore, what does the `now.className = "saturate";` do? i mean, is the word 'saturate' in this context my own function? originally, one of the four images had a `class="saturate"` which i randomly tried to remove, and the whole thing still worked, so i'm thinking the aforementioned saturate word might have had something to do with this. (i also style the .saturate in my CSS, which is where it gets the 80% extra saturation). how this effect still works after removing the `class="saturate"` from `<li><img id="one"`..i really dont understand.

Comment: There is likely some CSS which styles those images to look saturated when they have that class name

Answer (score 1):

As you've already mentioned, the CSS class class `saturate` is used to apply the visual effect.

Any element with that class applied (e.g. `class="saturate"`) will have the effect.

If I understand your JavaScript correctly, all it is doing is adding or removing that CSS class from an element when it is clicked.

The empty string (`current.className = ""`) is simply a way of removing all CSS classes from the element. So, if the user clicks and element that already has a CSS class (e.g. `class="saturate"`), that class will be removed, thereby removing the effect.

You asked why the effect still works when you remove the `class="saturate"` from an element's markup. That is because clicking the element will re-apply the class, as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img … onclick="saturate(this); display(this);" …>
```

Here you specify that when the image is clicked (`onclick`), the `saturate()` function is called. That function is called with a so-called parameter, namely `this`. In this context, `this` refers to the element being clicked, which is the `<img>` element.

---

Let's now take a look at the `saturate()` function:

```
function saturate(now) { … }
```

The function is defines with one parameter, named `now`. This means that the parameter that was previously passed to the function (the `this`, being the clicked `<img>`), is now accessible via the name `now`. So if we're inside this function, and we talk about `now`, we actually mean the clicked `<img>`.

---

Let's skip a few lines for now, we'll get back to that later.

---

`now.className = "saturate";`

What we say here, is that the `className` of `now` (the `<img>`) should become `saturate`. This is similar to manually adding the class, like this: `<img class="saturate">`. Your document probably contains some CSS, which specifies something for the `saturate` class (look for `.saturate` in your CSS). After running this line of code, that CSS is applied to the image.

---

```
current = now;
```

This line says that we'll have a new name, called `current`, that refers to the same thing as `now`. Since `now` referred to the `<img>` that was just clicked, `current` will now refer to that same image.

Because the variable `current` was defined outside of the function (in your first line of JavaScript), it's a so-called global variable. This means that `current` will exist forever, also after this function is done executing. So as long as we don't change `current`, it'll keep referring to the clicked `<img>`.

---

Now suppose you click another `<img>`. The same happens as described above, but we'll now take a look at the lines I just skipped:

```
if (current != null) {
    current.className = "";
}
```

(Remember that these are the first lines in the `saturate()` function. They are thus executed before the others.)

What we see here, is that we first check whether `current` is not empty using `if (current != null)`. Since we know that `current` refers to the `<img>` we clicked before, we know that it's not null.

Then the next line is executed: `current.className = ""`. This line changes the `className` of `current` (which is actually the previously clicked `<img>`) to empty. In other words, it removes the `saturate` class that was applied when we clicked that `<img>` before. That `<img>` will now thus no longer be saturated.

After this, the other two lines are executed, resulting in the newly clicked `<img>` to become saturated and to be assigned to `current`.